# sudo -E env not printing my PATH

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, environment-variables

I read the manpages but maybe I didn't understand them.. why is

```
sudo -E env PATH="$PATH" echo "$PATH"
```

printing out my environment variables but

```
sudo -E env MYPATH="$PATH" echo "$MYPATH"
```

is just printing an empty line?

Comment: Think about when `$MYPATH` in the list of arguments to `sudo` gets expanded.  Hint: it's before the shell calls `sudo`.